# Laravel : Change attribute Href with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, href

With Laravel,  i use url like that :

```
href="{{ asset ('theme/css/cv-style.css')}}
```

I try to change this url by starting escape url with jquery function :

```
 var test =  "{{ asset ('theme/css/cv-style.css')}} ";
    var testtext = $(test).text(htmlString);
```

But doesn't work.. 
I think it's cause " {{ }} "....   but how to escape this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, totaly my bad...
Wrong way for my problem.

I don't need to escape {{ }}

I had just bad utilisation of fonction .attr et .removeAttr

All it's good ,now.